# How easy is it to set up JBoss Seam to run on GlassFish with JPA instead of Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, glassfish, seam

Question pretty much says it all - I'm interested to find out about how to set up JBoss Seam on a GlassFish (v3 prelude) application server rather than JBoss. Also, I prefer JPA over Hibernate for persistance but it looks as though Seam has dependencies on Hibernate (or at least parts of it), has anyone got any experience with a stack like this?

Comment: Well one thing your question doesn't say is why you'd want to use Seam at all?  I've looked at it and I don't get the point.  It's really heavyweight and, more to the point, quite "closed" in that its heavily tied to JBoss/Hibernate.

Comment: Good question. I was looking at that a while ago as well. But as cletus said, it is tightly integrated with JBoss/Hibernate which stopped me from trying this setup.

Comment: Seam doesn't require JBoss or Hibernate, it was intially developed with them in mind, but you can use other stacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seam does not require Hibernate, and the recent 2.x releases are tested and documented to work on other application servers.

We have a Seam application that uses JPA, which was no problem to set-up. I do not use GlassFish, but the Seam manual has a section on [deploying the JPA example on GlassFish](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/glassfish.html#jpa-glassfish-section), which sounds like what you need.

Comment: This thread is old, so some URLs need to be updated. Look [here to know how to deploy Seam on Glassfish](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/glassfish.html).